# Excel 2003 How to pass params to SQL sproc (pivot based on external source)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, excel-2003, vba

I created Excel 2003 pivot table which uses External source and SQL 2008.

I wrote in the query:

```
exec mysproc '20110726', '20110727'
```

and it works fine. However I need to be able to pass the dates taken from Excel cells.

What is the cleanest/shortest solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Added button attached to the following sub:

```
Sub RefreshPivotQuery()

    Dim d1 As String
    Dim d2 As String

    d1 = Format(Sheets("Main").Range("Date1"), "yyyymmdd")
    d2 = Format(Sheets("Main").Range("Date2"), "yyyymmdd")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Pivot")

    ws.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.CommandText = "exec mysproc '" + d2 + "', '" + d1 + "'"

End Sub
```